# Vue.js image v-for bind

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Any way to use v-for to get an array of images loaded?

Have tried with the following code:

Im pretty new to Vue, I still have a lot to learn. So any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

```html
<template>
      <section class="hero_home">
         <app-header></app-header>
          <article>
            <h1>About</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Est, aperiam doloremque possimus nemo incidunt, consequatur quidem facere in ipsam ratione quod? Provident laborum magnam accusantium sequi optio error sunt, sit.</p>
        </article>

            <img v-for="image in images" :src="images.url" :alt="images.alt" />
        
        <app-footer></app-footer>
      </section>
</template>


<script>
    import Header from './header.vue'
    import Footer from './footer.vue'
    
    export default {
        components: {
            'app-header': Header,
            'app-footer': Footer
        },
      data () {
        return {
            images: [
                { url: '../static/1.jpg', alt: 'I love you nature' },
                { url: '../static/2.jpg', alt: 'Now with dog - Rosé' },
                { url: '../static/3.jpg', alt: 'Jeg er i Danmark' },
                { url: '../static/4.jpg', alt: 'Badabimbadabum' },
                { url: '../static/5.jpg', alt: 'Goodmorning el mundo' },
                { url: '../static/6.jpg', alt: 'My white and rosé with paella' },
                { url: '../static/7.jpg', alt: 'Hopla' },
                { url: '../static/8.jpg', alt: 'Watering by night' },
                { url: '../static/9.jpg', alt: 'Life aint so bad at all...' },
                { url: '../static/10.jpg', alt: 'My whitewine' },
                { url: '../static/11jpg', alt: 'First time for everything...winefair!' },
                { url: '../static/12.jpg', alt: 'Lost around 20% of this years yield!' }
            ]
        }
      }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use `image` object element, not `images` object array here in `src` and `alt`.

```html
<img v-for="image in images" :src="image.url" :alt="image.alt" />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Rishi!