# I can't upload the page with vue.js, where am I going wrong?

Tags: javascript, image, vue.js, frontend, v-for

```
<template>
   
    <form class="questionnaire-result" action="#">
        <h1 class="h1">Here are your result!</h1>
        <div class="grid-container">
            <h2 class="sub-club"> Sub-Club</h2>
            <h2 class="score"> Score</h2>
            <h2 class="join-que"> Want to Join?</h2>
            <div class="sub-club-section " v-for="(subclub) in subclubs" :key="subclub.id">
                    <div class="responsive">
                        <div class="gallery">
                            <img class="image" :src="subclub.path">
                            <div class="desc">{{subclub.name}}</div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    <h3 v-if="subclub.score>50" class="score-result" style="color:#0cf12a ">{{subclub.score}}%</h3>
                    <h3 v-else class="score-result" style="color:red ">{{subclub.score}}%</h3>
                    <div v-if="subclub.score>50">
                        <input class="join-btn option-input " type="checkbox" v-bind:value="subclub.name"  v-model="selected_subclubs" >
                    </div>
            </div>
     {{selected_subclubs}}
        <button @click=" goToHomePage()" class="button "><span> JOIN </span></button>
      
        </div>
    </form>

    </div>
  
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name:"QuestionnaireResult",
    data(){
      
        return{
            selected_subclubs:[],
            subclubs:[
             { 
                id:1,
                name:"Yoga",
                score:70,
                path:"@/assets/sub-clubs-images/Yoga_mini.jpeg",
              
                
            },
            
            ]
        }
    },
    methods:{
            goToHomePage(){
                this.$router.push("/");
            }
    }
}
</script>
```

I apply it like this , I put the path in the data to company src. It worked this way for many people. but I cannot put the image on the page . It works when I pass the path directly to the src as a string.I can't understand how I can't get the path.Can you help me.

I tried to do it like this: [Vue.js image v-for bind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44948916/vue-js-image-v-for-bind)

Comment: Please do not work with pictures it makes it harder to reproduce because we can't copy and paste

Comment: @SeppeMariën sorry , edited

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing and binding img src from props in Vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56624817/passing-and-binding-img-src-from-props-in-vue-js)

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the image from webpack using `require` to pass it using javascript

See these other posts for more details

[How to bind img src to data in Vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48847644/how-to-bind-img-src-to-data-in-vue)

[Passing and binding img src from props in Vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56624817/passing-and-binding-img-src-from-props-in-vue-js)